# Do you always make a branch off of `master` with GitHub Flow?

Tags: git, github

The following page (Understanding the GitHub Flow) says "it's extremely important that your new branch is created off of master."

https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Does this mean we shouldn't make a new branch off of an existing branch other than master? (That means, there are no parent branches. All branches are flat, not nested.) Or can we do this in some special cases?

I'm especially curious about if the people at GitHub always make a branch off of master, or if they have some exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction for branching off only from master, it totally depends on the requirement.

Consider you work in sprints and every sprint dev work is done is new branch

```
  $git branch
   master
  $git checkout -b sprint1
```

In the following sprint1, multiple functionalities to be built so further sub branches can be pulled from sprint1.

```
  $git branch
  sprint1
  $git checkout -b ui_design
```

So this branch ui_design is not off the master but surely linked. 
While merging the changes from the branches, you need to be careful. Below steps can also be followed,

```
  $ git checkout -b backend sprint1
```

Creates backend branch off sprint1. Perform the changes and commit it, Next merge your changes back to sprint1.

```
  $ git checkout sprint1
  $ git merge --no-ff backend
```

Now push your changes to respective branches sprint1 and backend.

Comment: My question is, can we call this GitHub Flow? I think the biggest merit of GitHub Flow is, creating a branch from master and merge it to master and deploy when it's done. With you case, we need to wait for the sprint1 release.

Comment: No this is normal github flow and you can merge the changes anytime, sprint1 is just a use case with any duration.